# NT to UNIX group mapping in Samba 4

Tags: linux, windows, unix, samba

I want to map the NT Group `Domain Users` to a different UNIX group than `users` on my Samba 4.7.6 Active Directory Domain Controller, but when I try to do this, it fails as follows:

```
> net groupmap modify ntgroup='Domain Users' unixgroup='share' type=domain
Could not update group database
[255]
```

I read that you might now do this with winbind, so I tried, but then I get the following error.

```
> wbinfo --set-gid-mapping=1000,S-1-5-21-...-513
failed to call wbcSetGidMapping: WBC_ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
Could not create or modify gid to sid mapping
[1]
```

**What is the proper way to manage NT to UNIX group mapping in Samba 4?**

**EDIT:** On the Samba mailing list I found someone with a [similar problem](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2009-May/148424.html), so maybe I could work around it by modifying the internal LDAP server directly? Something like:

```
ldbadd /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/metadata.tdb ...
```

Unfortunately I have no experience with LDAP, so I don't know how to supply it with a valid LDIF file for my use case.

**EDIT2:** Thanks to a [blogpost about Samba 4 user and group management in LDAP](https://linuxcostablanca.blogspot.nl/2012/02/samba-4-posix-domain-user.html), I managed to edit the UNIX group that the NT group maps to:

```
> ldbedit -e nano -H /var/lib/samba/private/idmap.ldb '(objectSid=S-1-5-21-1580746459-3543417057-3597883204-513)'

> wbinfo --group-info='Domain Users'
AD.EXAMPLE\domain users:x:100:

> net groupmap list ntgroup='Domain Users'
Domain Users (S-1-5-21-1580746459-3543417057-3597883204-513) -> share
```

So the right group is now being reported by `net groupmap`, but `wbinfo` still reports the old value, so it probably does not get its data from that database. I am not sure how important `wbinfo` reporting the right group is for my use case, but I will see if I can change that as well before using this as my answer and marking it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have been able to piece together it seems that there is no tool available in Samba 4 that allows you to configure this properly, other than editing the built-in LDAP server directly.

The `net` tool does not seem to work well with the built-in LDAP server, only some operations are successful, e.g. listing the group mappings and granting rights work, but listing members of a group or modifying the group mappings does not work (as seen in my question).

To modify the mapping I ran the following commands as root. First we have to retrieve the SID of `Domain Users`, because it will be unique for each provisioning of the Samba server.

```
root> net groupmap list ntgroup='Domain Users'
Domain Users (S-1-5-21-1580746459-3543417057-3597883204-513) -> users
```

Then we update the built-in LDAP server's record for the SID by updating `xidNumber: 100` with the intended UNIX GID:

```
root> ldbedit -e nano -H /var/lib/samba/private/idmap.ldb '(objectSid=S-1-5-21-1580746459-3543417057-3597883204-513)'
# 0 adds  1 modifies  0 deletes
```

Let's say you changed it to the GID `250` of the UNIX group called `share`, then calling `net groupmap` will result in the group reported back being `share`:

```
root> net groupmap list ntgroup='Domain Users'
Domain Users (S-1-5-21-1580746459-3543417057-3597883204-513) -> share
```

However `wbinfo` of `winbindd` will still report the old GID:

```
root> wbinfo --group-info='Domain Users'
AD.EXAMPLE\domain users:x:100:
```

So we have to invalidate the cache entry for `Domain Users`. After some experimentation I managed to do so by asking it to lookup the updated GID:

```
root> wbinfo --gid-info 250
AD.EXAMPLE\domain users:x:250:
```

Which is then also reported back correctly by `--group-info`:

```
root> wbinfo --group-info='Domain Users'
AD.EXAMPLE\domain users:x:250:
```